# How does javascript Set can keep the order of insertion and still have 0(1) lookup "Set.has()"?

Tags: javascript, set, hashtable

I have been studying data structures and I do get that Set use implementation similar to hash tables, so the input value + the hash algorithm will create a index where the value is stored...

This will yield the ability to search for such value later in constant time o(1) (disregarding collisions) however this comes at expense of not having an ordered collection since the positions in the collection are computed during insertion instead of order insertion,

So the question is how Set can keep the order and still have constant time on the lookup method Set.has()?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I imagine it's similar to Java's [LinkedHashSet](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashSet.html)

Comment: I've a feeling the specification doesn't force any Javascript engine on how it's implemented.  But there is nothing stopping the engine using a standard hashmap and a linked list to achieve it.

Comment: When a new 'node' is added, it can be linked to 'last node' added. Consider that the nodes themselves located in some hash structure can be objects such as `(key, prev_node, next_node)` forming an implicit linked list. (Of course, for small sets it's more efficient to use a simpler structure, such as an array which implicitly has an ordering, and claim O(1) simpler <= O(1) more_complex, for some limited N.)

Comment: I agree with @Phil. Stated more generally, if you want O(1) lookup, implement with a hash. If you want O(1) sequencing, implement with a list/array. If you want both, implement with both.